# How to line break between records within the same bookmark?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm currently trying to merge the data from msaccess to a word template that has bookmarks in place.

I currently have the code below,

```
Dim wApp as Word.Application
Dim wDoc as Word.Document
Dim rs As Dao.Recordset
    
set wApp=Word.document
set wdoc = wapp.documents.open(filepath)
set rs = currentdb.openrecordset("ftions")
    
rs.movelast
rs.movefirst
do while not rs.eof
    doevents 
        wdoc.bookmarks("Fname").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Fname, "")

rs.MoveNext
Loop

Set doc = nothing
Set wdoc = nothing
rs.close
set rs = nothing

end sub
```

However, my output becomes like this instead

[fname1][fname2]

when I want them to appear in a list

a. [fname1]

b. [fname2]

Comment: Maybe `wdoc.bookmarks("Fname").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Fname, "") & vbCrLf` instead?

Comment: @braX Thanks for that, sovled the next line issue. However, is there also anyway for a list to appear? as in bulletin points

Comment: `wdoc.bookmarks("Fname").Range.Text = "• " & Nz(rs!Fname, "") & vbCrLf`

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments above, just use this in your loop. (bullets included)

```
wdoc.bookmarks("Fname").Range.Text = "• " & Nz(rs!Fname, "") & vbCrLf
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by braX, issue was solved with

```
Dim wApp as Word.Application
Dim wDoc as Word.Document
Dim rs As Dao.Recordset
    
set wApp=Word.document
set wdoc = wapp.documents.open(filepath)
set rs = currentdb.openrecordset("ftions")
    
rs.movelast
rs.movefirst
do while not rs.eof
    doevents 
        wdoc.bookmarks("Fname").Range.Text = "• " & Nz(rs!Fname, "") & vbCrLf

rs.MoveNext
Loop

Set doc = nothing
Set wdoc = nothing
rs.close
set rs = nothing

end sub
```